# from _decimal import Decimal AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'

Tags: python, python-3.x

While running the code, the following error has occured.

```
from _decimal import Decimal
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the piece of code generating that error ?

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but for those who encounter this error.

In this case `import` trying to find module `'numbers'` in the current directory.

So the solution is to check the directory for such files (`numbers.py`) and rename them.

See info about [python import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for details.